# How to account for known bias in classification data

Tags: classification, bias, noise

I apologize for the vagueness beforehand. Here's my experimental setup. I am trying to see if a data point has a property `p`. For example, in an image classification dataset, `p` can be whether the image contains a tree.

An ideal classification scenario would be that I label some data points to see if they have property `p` or not. However, that is not possible on a large scale. I do have a tiny dataset that has been annotated in this way.

I have access to some data which was generated in a particular way. Extending on the example, imagine at some point people were asked to take pictures of trees and I have access to a large sample of such data. Obviously, this has *only* positive labels. This is also *biased*: if you are asked to take a picture of a tree you would probably keep it at the center, as opposed to when you are just taking random pictures and sometimes a tree happens to be in it.

Moreover, I can generate negative data points using some heuristics, such as there is no green pixel in the picture. This also will introduce some bias.

My question is, are there statistical methods to control for these biases in the classifier model? Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a number of thoughts roughly grouped by topic:

- With image classification, you will often have to worry less about having a sample of images that is truly samples in proportion to how often each thing occurs in the real world. That's mostly because for many use cases the signal of "There's a tree here!" is so strong that the bias arising from over-sampling some class is often mostly irrelevant. With more subtle associations that tends to be much more of a problem. So, one possibility is whether to some extent the original fully labelled dataset and the dataset of just positives together work well. While trying that, you could try to oversample (in your image generator) the images without trees. I'd want to really carefully test (i.e. on a set of well-labelled images that closely remsemble your target setting and were not used for training) the resulting model though, because I'd be a bit worried about that (like you seem to be). There's a bunch of things that could go wrong (different dataset sources, for a start, could have different cameras and you might end up building a camera detector, one source might always have a certain type of background etc.).
- Unless a model on just what you have performs well, you probably need more labelled images from both classes. So, my remaining thoughts are all around that. However, different options will work better in different settings (I don't quite know what is the hardest for you to get/do/pay for).
- A really good solution is of course to send out more humans to take pictures of trees and "equivalent" landscapes without trees (and to provide labels as to what the picture shows). Presumably that's for some reason not easy to do.
- You may well end up doing some more human labelling (whether that's crowd sourced labelling or you personally or your team etc.) of images that are out there, but your problem is to find the right candidates for labelling that are even vaguely relevant to your question. Unless you want to do a ImageNet sized effort, one challenge will be how to cut things down so that you pre-select images of the right kind of setting you want your model to work in. If you want to e.g. check whether there's trees in images of landscapes in the American Mid-West, then you really want lots of images of landscapes in the American Mid-West (perhaps to match your second dataset created using a similar camera - which maybe you can sometimes get from image-meta-data). Some publically available sources of photos might have location tags associated with them, some might have human assigned tags or labels, and those things might have. Or perhaps the setting is closely aligned to a few categories in ImageNet, so you could run your candidate photos through there and look for those that are likely in those categories. Another idea could be to try using image captioning models and look which images are described as something similar to what you are looking for (you could even train your own one somewhat tailored to your use case).
- Can you get lots of unlabelled images from your actual use case? You could apply active learning (after creating an initial model) to identify the images that would be most worth labelling.
- Could you get humans to cut the images you have into bits. Then you classify the bits as "has tree" or "has no tree" and train on that. That could work, because even an image with a tree will have areas without one. You may have to make sure the workflow does not result in high resolution big bits and low resolution small bits being more common in one class (i.e. perhaps make all the bits the same size?). At inference time you might either have to either cut the image up, or perhaps it would work without doing that (probably needs to be tested via cross-validation to check).
- Could you get humans to do segmentation (or bounding boxes) for where the tree is in the image (even more time consuming to label, but also provides a stronger signal).